# Python: Use input of a function as part of the name of a data frame within the function

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I want to define a function that can takes different data frame by changing the input. For example, with

```
def test (Source): 
    print('df'+ Source)
```

I would like to run test('A') and get data frame df_A, run test('B') and get data frame df_B, etc. But its only reading 'df_A' as a string not a table. df_A and df_B are pre defined.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use globals(), it will return you a dictionary with variable names in string format as keys and the variable value as the corresponding value for that key.

So, the following code solves the above issue

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
df_A = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])
print(df_A)

data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'Steve', 'Ricky'],'Age':[28,34,29,42]}
df_B = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df_B)

def test (Source): 
    formatted_string = "df_"+Source
    if formatted_string in globals().keys():
        print(globals()[formatted_string])

test("A")
test("B")
```

Answer (score 0):

The print command is only printing the concatenated string you built using 'df' and your input variable source. 
**To get the actual data, you need to use the eval() function as follows:**

```py
def test (Source): 
    return eval('df_' + Source)
```

This will return the output as if you had i.e df_a in a Jupyter cell.